# Are the phrases “both in water and land” and “for the loss and damage to” grammatical?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, ellipses

I have asked this question in a linguistics forum, but as I was not getting answers I decided to ask it here.

A. Consider the phrase that is boldfaced in sentence (1):

1. "It can live **both in water and land**."

Is the phrase grammatical as it is, with no preposition before "land"? Or should the phrase be "both in water and on land"?

B. Now consider the phrase that is boldfaced in sentence (2):

2. "He is responsible **for the loss and damage to** the article."

In the phrase grammatical as it is, with no preposition after "loss"? Or should the phrase be "loss of and damage to"?

Comment: Where multiple conflicting prepositions are involved, we usually force consistency for the *last* one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So "last" one means?

Comment: It means idiomatically people are more likely to accept your (2) because the final preposition is valid (though pedants could argue that there's an implication *the loss* might be ***of*** something other than "the article"). They're less likely to accept (1) because the "deleted" preposition ***in*** doesn't really work with "land". But many if not most would simply rephrase sufficiently to avoid the conflict.

Comment: I've found a different rule for this. The preposition that should be kept is the one that is closest to the subject being described by the preposition, which would make both of these correct.

Answer (score 1):

"It can live both in water and land."

A good trick I use for these types of situations is to imagine it says: "It can live both in water and in land" since that's basically what you're saying. For this you need to add "and on land." Otherwise you're saying it can live in land as well.

"He is responsible for the loss and damage to the article."

For this sentence, use the same trick I said for the previous sentence: "He is responsible for the loss to the article and damage to the article." The phrase "loss to the article" doesn't seem to have the meaning you were going for, so again I'd say add "loss of."

Comment: Very good answer.  I think your trick is really great to help the asker in any generalized case.  I would add to the specific example of the damaged article that you're not going to have to deal with loss *and* damage since loss makes damage unknowable and irrelevant.  So I would suggest "He is responsible for any loss of or damage to the article."

Answer (score 0):

I would add *on* to land and *any* to damage since

> He is responsible for any loss or damage to the article

is the most widely used version of this sentence

Comment: Why do you say it's most widely used with *any*? [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+any+loss+or+damage%2Cfor+loss+or+damage%2C+for+the+loss+or+damage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20any%20loss%20or%20damage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20loss%20or%20damage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20loss%20or%20damage%3B%2Cc0). (I agree that *any* is better than *the*, but no article is more widely used.)

Comment: @PeterShor How to decide which one is correct, especially when in first sentence we are using different different prepositions for different nouns and in case of second sentence we are using only one preposition for the nearer noun?

Comment: @Man_From_India: I would say that strictly speaking, *"loss of or damage to"* is more correct, but *"loss or damage to"* is slightly more widely used. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loss+or+damage+to%2Closs+of+or+damage+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Closs%20or%20damage%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Closs%20of%20or%20damage%20to%3B%2Cc0). English speakers are careless with these types of thing.

Comment: @PeterShor So in case of the first sentence "both in water and on land" is the correct version. But I think the "both in water and land" is widely used version. In that case I guess the preposition is agreeing to the nearer noun. Is it true?

Comment: Actually, *in water and on land* is more widely used, but *in water and land* is also quite common. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+water+and+on+land%2C+in+water+and+land&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20water%20and%20on%20land%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20water%20and%20land%3B%2Cc0). And if you only put in one preposition, you'd certainly want the preposition to agree with the nearer noun (or verb).

Comment: "It can live both in water and land" is going to sound wrong to native speakers - particularly ones who will think of it literally...is the animal a mole that lives "in" the land?  The first example should have separate prepositions..."in water and on land".  The 2nd example may leave a legal loophole open for interpretation and is better handled with explicit prepositions as well, IMO.

Comment: @KristinaLopez So what is the rule? Is it okay to make preposition agree with the last preposition?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good with the rules, like some of the others here, but I have a pretty good sense of what is communicated clearly and what is ambiguous.

Comment: @Peter Shor - any idea how many of the ngrams for the letter involve constructions like "in water and land use studies" etc.?  I suspect most of those involve water/land used as noun adjuncts (adjectivally).

Comment: @Mark: it looks like a lot of them, but not all, are noun adjuncts.